# Next js Dynamic Routes image gives 400 error

Tags: image, next.js, routes, 400-bad-request

I am new on the next js and I want to use [lang] dynamic route for changing language and inside that route not found image. Image gives 400 error
And my routes and I am using app directory structure
app/[lang]/[dashboard/users/page.tsx not found image and my image located on public/images/avatar.png

If I open outside of [lang] route one route at that place working and find that image but If I same code put it on the inside [lang] route 400 error gives